# dart_test: how to execute `setUp` if a loop before `test` is used based on the data assigned in `setUp`?

Tags: dart, unit-testing, testing

The problem is in this code:

```dart
void main() {
  late List<int> data;

  setUp(() async {
    data = [11, 22, 33];
  });
  
  int counter = 0;
  for (final d in data) { // error
    test('data', () {
      expect(d, data[counter++]);
    });
  }
}
```

**error**:

```
Local 'data' has not been initialized.
```

*How can we specify that the `setUp` function should be called before the data is used?*

I tried wrapping `test` in `group` - same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of agony, I found an optimal solution that allows you to use collection sets and call `setUp` and `tearDown` exactly at test time.

Look, here's a simple wrapper:

```dart
@isTest
Future<void> testWith(
  Object description,
  dynamic Function() body, {
  dynamic Function()? setUp,
  dynamic Function()? tearDown,
}) async {
  test(description, () async {
    await setUp?.call();
    await body.call();
    await tearDown?.call();
  });
}
```

Add the desired parameters as needed. Also everything can be asynchronous and work fine.

Now we can execute this code (slightly expanded to demonstrate the capabilities):

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  late List<int> data;
  Future<void> setUpAction() async {
    print('setUpAction');
    data = [11, 22, 33];
  }

  Future<void> tearDownAction() async {
    print('tearDownAction');
    data = [];
  }

  await testWith(
    'Test_1 data',
    setUp: setUpAction,
    tearDown: tearDownAction,
    () {
      int counter = 0;
      for (final d in data) {
        print('test_1: $d');
        expect(d, data[counter++]);
      }
    },
  );

  await testWith(
    'Test_2 data',
    setUp: setUpAction,
    tearDown: tearDownAction,
    () {
      int counter = 0;
      for (final d in data.take(2)) {
        print('test_1: $d');
        expect(d, data[counter++]);
      }
    },
  );
}
```

The output to the console is as follows:

```
setUpAction
test_1: 11
test_1: 22
test_1: 33
tearDownAction
setUpAction
test_1: 11
test_1: 22
tearDownAction
```

---

If we use the `setUpAction` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77562346/17991131), we get two problems:

- calling `setUpAction` will happen twice and we will be testing not exactly what is intended
- there is no possibility to use multiple tests, because all tests are collected into a list and only then start executing. The point has been demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77562780/17991131).

---

Add the `isTest` annotation so idea can see your tests (if necessary, there is also an `isTestGroup` annotation) from package `meta`:

> Used to annotate a test framework function that runs a single test.
> Tools, such as IDEs, can show invocations of such function in a file structure view to help the user navigating in large test files.
> The first parameter of the function must be the description of the test.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that `setUp` and `test` take *callbacks* as arguments that will be executed at some unspecified later time but with some relative ordering.  Specifically, `setUp` registers a callback that will be executed before each `test` callback is executed.

Here is the sequence of events:

1. `setUp` registers its callback.
2. The `for`-loop executes.
3. `test` is called on each iteration of loop, registering a callback.
4. The `for`-loop exits.
5. The tests execute, which for each test consists of:

   1. The `setUp` callback from step 1 is executed.
   2. The `test` callback from step 3 is executed.

The `for`-loop does not exist within a `test` callback; it executes immediately after `setUp` registers its callback.  There is no way to automatically execute that `setUp` callback before the `for`-loop.  If you really wanted to, you could explicitly make the callback a named function that you explicitly invoke:

```dart
void main() {
  late List<int> data;

  void setUpAction() {
    data = [11, 22, 33];
  }

  setUp(setUpAction);
  setUpAction();
  
  int counter = 0;
  for (final d in data) {
    test('data', () {
      expect(d, data[counter++]);
    });
  }
}
```

However, `setUp` should be used to reset shared state before executing each test, but your tests don't mutate any shared state.  Therefore you don't even need `setUp` in your case:

```dart
void main() {
  const data = [11, 22, 33];

  int counter = 0;
  for (final d in data) {
    test('data', () {
      expect(d, data[counter++]);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually have a shared state) and calling `setUp` is necessary. At the moment the most working option is to use your own `setUpCustom` and call it every time before the test, without having to call `setUp` at all. If anything, `tearDown`, which I also need, will it work as intended?

Comment: @Ruble It doesn't make sense to have shared state that is mutated during the `for`-loop.  The tests don't execute within the `for`-loop; the `for`-loop *registers* test callbacks.  I've updated my answer to try to clarify that point.  Whatever it is you're iterating over should be constant.  As for `tearDown`, it is the other half of `setUp`: it registers a callback that will called at the end of every test.

Answer (score 0):

@jamesdlin 's answer helped, thanks to him. Here's code demonstrating the behavior:

```dart
void main() {
  late List<int> data;

  void setUpCustom([int? numb]) {
    print('with $numb: setUp called');
    data = [11, 22, if (numb != null) numb];
  }

  setUp(setUpCustom);
  tearDown(() {
    print('tearDown called');
    data = [];
  });

  setUpCustom(33);
  int counter = 0;
  for (final d in data) {
    test('data', () {
      print('in test: $d, $counter $data');
      expect(d, data[counter++]);
    });
  }

  setUpCustom(44);
  //...
}
```

Will print:

```
with 33: setUp called
with 44: setUp called
with null: setUp called
in test: 11, 0 [11, 22]
tearDown called
with null: setUp called
in test: 22, 1 [11, 22]
tearDown called
with null: setUp called
in test: 33, 2 [11, 22]
dart:core             List.[]
test\test.dart 97:21  main.<fn>
tearDown called

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2
```

If you don't plan to use the arguments in `setUpCustom`, this could all be quite workable. True, the semantics of such code will not be a good gift...